# Site sub-pages display only the homepage

Tags: wordpress

The site I’m working on is a Wordpress one-page type of site.
I’ve created two pages that should be accessible with their specific urls, these are not displayed on the main menu. I concider them as hidden pages.
The urls were working fine until this week. Now if I try to load the pages, the site just display the homepage. It’s not a redirection because the url doesn’t change, but the content displayed is the homepage.

As far as I know no changes were made to the site, nothing that could explain why it was working fine before but not anymore. Maybe it’s due to a WordPress update ?

What should I concider looking into ? I’m not an expert of WordPress so any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check log for errors. What happens if you type the problem page url directly ?